# Holomorphic invective map of an annulus is a rotation

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, maximum-principle

Let $f$ be a holomorphic one-to-one mapping of the annulus $1 ≤ |z| ≤ 2$, taking the inner boundary onto itself and the outer boundary onto itself. Show that $f$ is a rotation.

I considered function $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}$ and have shown that it attains maximum at the boundary. How to show that it is constant by max-modulus principle?

Comment: What is $\lvert g(z)\rvert$ for $z$ in the boundary?

Comment: $|g(z)|=1$ on the boundary

Comment: I am not sure how the injectivness will come into play

Comment: For one version of the maximum modulus principle that already suffices. For a different version, also look at $h(z) = 1/g(z)$.

Comment: Now $|h(z)$ will attain its maximum 1 also on the boundary, does this imply $|g(z)| attains minimum on the boundary? Also why do we need the one to one part then? does it hold for all such functions?

Comment: Yes, $\lvert g(z)\rvert$ also attains its minimum on the boundary. And indeed, the injectivity hypothesis is redundant, a holomorphic self-map of an annulus that extends continuously to the boundary and maps the boundary to itself is automatically injective.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!